# .NET , include dlls in nuget package, but not list them when referencing it

Tags: .net, nuget

I am trying to make a NuGet package that contains dlls and resources of multiple (local) folders, in such a way that when the package is referenced, all those items are copied to the output folder of the project referencing my package, but without listing all these items as "content" of the project referencing my package.

I have a .NET project called `CefBrowser`, netcoreapp3.1 , whose .csproj contains:

```
    <Content Include="$(NuGetPackageRoot)\cef.redist.x86\113.1.4\CEF\*">
      <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
      <PublishState>Included</PublishState>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
```

I make the CefBrowser nuget package using the command `dotnet pack`.
The DLLs (e.g. `chrome_elf.dll`, native dll) and resources (e.g. `icudtl.dat`) originally contained in `$(NuGetPackageRoot)\cef.redist.x86\113.1.4\CEF\` are included in my CefBrowser package (as intended), in `\contentFiles\any\netcoreapp3.1\` and in `\content\`.

However, when the package is built I get a warning like this, for each dll:

```
warning NU5100: The assembly 'content\chrome_elf.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced. [D:\CefBrowser\CefBrowser.csproj]
```

When I reference the resulting NuGet package, the dlls and resources are included in the binaries folder of the application, but all the items in the package are listed as linked files.

[Screenshot of the application project referencing my CefBrowser nuget package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozCwT.png)

I've been reading the article [Common MSBuild project items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022) but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

I tried with `Content Include`, `None Include`, and many other things without success, but I think it is not worth describing it here given that I tried combinations without knowing/understanding their expected outcome. So any guidance on the correct way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you make `cef.redist.x86` a dependency of your package instead? If someone references your package, but also `cef.redist.x86` (whether directly, or transitively), there's no benefit to them having two copies of the DLL. Plus if a single project references both packages, embedding the dlls in your package prevents NuGet from being able to do version management.